# Template to PDF conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am building a doctor portal application where there will be multiple doctors looking after patients. Each doctor will have their own letterhead for creating prescriptions and will have flexibility of updating and managing the prescription letterhead format.
My app will have python backend and react js frontend. When a doctor logs in to the portal they can add certain medication and generate a PDF prescription to be shared with patient. The PDF prescription should be on the letterhead which is for that specific doctor. Basically a doctor can create some sort of basic template with placeholders for patient name and prescription text, which will be populated by backend at the time of creating a PDF prescription.

My question:
What will be the best format for the template - I have explored docx and HTML. If I use docx then it will be easier for the doctor to update the template but its difficult to replace placeholders as python-docx library doesn't allow to read text in textboxes and also in order to replace the placeholder I need to know the structure of the doc like if there are tables. With HTML i feel it will be easier to replace placeholder but it will be difficult for doctor's to maintain the template as they can't edit HTML and then I will have to create a UI to allow them to edit.
Is there any other format that I can use for the template which is easy to maintain and  I can replace the placeholders agnostically without having to know the document structure and then convert to PDF

For now I am thinking of storing the letterhead templates in google drive so that doctors have easy access

Answer (score 1):

For your application, considering the requirements you mentioned, there are a few options you can explore for the template format:

- `Markdown`: It allows you to create structured documents with simple formatting. You can use placeholders within the Markdown template and replace them programmatically. Markdown can be converted to HTML or PDF using various libraries or tools, making it a flexible choice for your application.
- `LaTeX`: LaTeX is a typesetting system commonly used for scientific and technical documents. It provides extensive control over document formatting and is highly customizable. You can create a LaTeX template with placeholders and use a `Python` library like `pylatex` or `reportlab` to replace the placeholders and generate a PDF. LaTeX does have a learning curve, but it offers powerful features for document layout and formatting.

> Both `Markdown` and `LaTeX` provide a good balance between ease of maintenance and flexibility for generating PDF documents with placeholders. You can choose the format that best suits your requirements and the technical expertise of your doctors.